# What is the right approach to parse unstructured but somewhat hierarchical data from a file?

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing

I'm learning Python and I want to be able to do the following. As long as I'm still in Item1, I want to find all subsectors and gather the data within the subsectors until I hit the next subsector. Being in Subsector1 the data can be of depth/length 4 or 5 until the next data block is reached. There are no empty lines in the file but I could do a regex on each DataX to figure out what it is and where it belongs. A normal entry includes 4 lines. If it's 5 until the next Data1 I want to concat Data1 + Data2 and go on. This process repeats for all subsectors until Item2 is reached and all subsectors and there data are being extracted. The process ends when there are no more lines to parse.

I'm coming to the conclusion that I probably need to write a line parser with look ahead. Does something in the Python ecosystem exists or is there a simpler approach?

The data comes from a normal text file line by line but the structure I want to extract looks something lime this:

```
Item1

    SubSector1

    Data1
    Data2 
    Data3
    Data4
    Data5 [if 5 then Data1 belongs to Data2]

    Data1
    Data2
    Data3
    Data4

    ...

    SubSector2

    Data1
    ...
    Data4

    Data1
    ...
    Data5

    SubSector3
    ...

Item2

    SubSector1

    Data1
    ...
    Data4

    SubSector3
    ...

Item3
    ...
```

In the end I want to create a CSV file that would have the following structure:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
SubSector1, Item1, Data1 + Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5
SubSector1, Item1, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4
SubSector2, Item1, Data1 + Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5
SubSector3, Item1, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4
SubSector1, Item2, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4
SubSector1, Item2, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4
SubSector1, Item3, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4
SubSector1, Item3, Data1 + Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You used yourself the key word: "depth".

Use a recursive function: when you encounter either a new item or a subsector, you return, providing to caller:

- Encountered a `Data`: add value in a `Data` array. Array is empty at start of a `SubSector`.
- Encountered a `SubSector`: return array of `Data` read since start of `SubSector`.
- Encountered a `Item`: return array of `SubSector`, each containing an array of `Data`.
- Encountered end of file: Return an array of `Items`, each containing an array of `SubSector`, each containing an array of `Data`. Also, reading process is obviously done.
- The line/key just read that broke the reading loop: since you don't have "close" markers (like XML), you'll return the "open" marker that you read "unnecessarily" - so caller can call itself recursively with the proper mode. It will also saves you to read ahead / go back in file, which can be a pain with text files if you didn't load them fully into memory.
- No line/key must be altered until "consumed" by something. If the `Data` part is reading an `Item`, then the middle `SubSector` part must NOT alter the line/key before returning to the `Item` part.

In fact, if the file structure is so simple and isn't planned to have any evolution or added depth level, you can even do it without recursivity and simply nest three "while" loops, each loop maintaining an index corresponding to the current depth level (`Item`, `SubSector` or `Data`) and creating corresponding arrays once the inner loop exits.